# Set value of ComboBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, combobox, controls

I need to set the selected value of a `ComboBox` in `UWP`.
The value that needs to be set is retrieved from a database.
How do I do this?
I have tried:
`ShipmentTypeComboBox.Text = editPackage.ShipmentType`, (amongst other options) but that doesn't work. The value appears only when I click the `ComboBox`.

- I want to retrieve the value from the database when the page is
  loaded (working).
- Display that value in the `ComboBox` (not working)

It's worth noting that this is a `ComboBox` whose `IsEditable` property is set to `True`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I set the Text of ComboBox, it displayed well and I didn't need to click ComboBox to display it. So I can't reproduce this issue, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Thanks, I ended up making a test app, and indeed setting the Text property of ComboBox works. I think I was loading the data before the page was loaded completely. Moved my logic to `Page_Loaded` instead of `OnNavigatedTo` and everything works as planned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:
I was loading the data on the `OnNavigatedTo` event.
I moved my logic to the `Page_Loaded` event and it works now.


I hope this helps someone who faces the same issue.
Thanks to everyone who commented.